# Can I use "perfect fit" to describe the way somebody chooses in doing something?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can I use "perfect fit" to describe the way somebody chooses to do things?

For example,

> Perhaps, some time in the future she will have to switch to a more
>   active mode of learning, but the pace she's been taking so far is just
>   a **perfect fit** for her at the current stage of her English studies.

or

> She decided to take these classes only 3 times a week, while her
>   competitors took as many as two or even three classes a day. This , of
>   course, may lead to her ultimate failure in the final showdown, but
>   given her peculiar character and unstable psychology, I would say that
>   the frequency that she has chosen is just **a perfect fit** for her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is a good use of the phrase "a perfect fit". I would say, however, that using 'just' before it makes it very informal/ colloquial and doesn't match the tone of the rest of the paragraph.

"...he pace she's been taking so far is a perfect fit for her..."
and
"I would say that the frequency that she has chosen is a perfect fit for her."

are better in my opinion.